# FATAL EXEPTION при попытке создать экземпляр класса OutputStream

Tags: java, android, классы

При попытке создать экземпляр класса `OutputStream` вылетает FATAL EXEPTION, что не так?

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String type = params[0];
    if (type == "login") {
        String login_url = "https://mysite/android.php";
        try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            return "ok";//result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "not login";
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog.setMessage("onPreExecute");
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage("onPostExecute");
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Log ошибки:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: ru.nanoserv.nano, PID: 2764
>                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>                         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>                         at ru.nanoserv.nano.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:37)
>                         at ru.nanoserv.nano.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Application terminated.

Comment: У вас ошибка в строке MainActivity.java:77. Спорим, вы там запускаете doInBackground напрямую, вместо вызова execute?

Comment: да так и есть, но это не единственная ошибка

Comment: даже если через execute() запускать приложение вылетает

Comment: Другую ошибку надо искать в другом месте

Comment: если убрать строку:  OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(); , а точнее httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(); то все работает подскажите на что обратить внимание?

Comment: используйте execute

Comment: спасибо, попробую